# Can I attach corrugated steel to cinder block for added privacy?

Tags: fence, addition

After looking for ways to help improve privacy between me and my nextdoor neighbors I thought about buying 8ft long panels of corrugated steel and fastening them to our six foot cinder block wall. I plan on just setting them at the ground level and having the corrugated lines run up and down vertically. I'm going for a very modern austere look so this would not only function well for privacy needs but also work with my design style.

It's against city code for me to build anything on top of the fence but there's nothing that states I can't attach anything to the fence on my side. I wanted to know what is the best type of anchor screw for this type of application and if anyone has done this before and how successful they were.

I live in the desert with an average rainfall of only four inches yearly so I don't think I'd have to worry about water and moisture causing damage to the cinder block with a piece of metal in permanent contact with it over the long haul.

Lastly, would an [anchor bolt](https://www.menards.com/main/hardware/fasteners-connectors/bolts/anchor-bolts/grip-fast-reg-1-2-x-10-hot-dipped-galvanized-anchor-bolt-w-nut-washer-2-count/1210hgab/hardware/fasteners-connectors/bolts/anchor-bolts/grip-fast-reg-1-2-x-8-hot-dipped-galvanized-anchor-bolt-w-nut-washer-2-count/128hgab/p-1444439570032.htm) with nut and washer added at the top provide me with more support?:

What I'm thinking of doing is drilling a hole in the corrugated panels so that the hole allows me to thread this anchor through it. The hole would be in alignment with the very top of the cinder block wall. I'd have the hook end on the opposite side grabbing onto the wall and on my side I'd tighten the bolt. I would want to add something like this for added strength since we get some high winds in the area from time to time. I think an extra two feet isn't much to worry about but I'm by no means an expert. Hence why I'm here asking for input.

Any suggestions for anchoring these panels to help me create my project would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to double check the city code. In a lot of places the maximum height for a fence/wall is 6ft  -  fixing panels to the fence which are 8ft high would probably be viewed as raising the height above the legal limit.

Of course this would only be an issue if the neighbours actually complained about it.

Comment: Those are designed to anchor a wall into poured concrete or filled cinder blocks. The rounded bend won't grab well to the squared edge of a cinder block. Also, if the hook of that anchor is on the neighbor's side of the wall, a few blows with a hammer would allow him to knock them loose.

Comment: How would corrugated steel add privacy  ? Do you mean sound absorption ? It would be worthless for sound control.

Comment: I just want to block their windows that look right into my home and windows. As far as sound absorption thankfully that's not a big issue. It's very quiet here.

Comment: Also, the previous owner used 8ft long landscape timbers that looked like red stained logs and attached them up against the wall vertically about every six feet and then hung some really nasty bamboo blinds/roller shades at the top and let them hang down that, of course, didn't weather well in the desert heat. In the summers here it can get up to 120 degrees. So naturally this option failed fast. Not to mention, it was ugly as hell. Everyone around here wants privacy so no neighbor would complain about my addition.

Comment: Some folks thing corrugated metal is "ugly as hell", Maybe even your neighbor.  I envision  high winds whipping the tops of the panels around wildly creating a super awesome soundscape for miles around.

Comment: @Alaska Man: If you read through my description you'd know that the 8ft panels of corrugated steel are going to be attached vertically. So only two feet of the actual panels would above the fence. There's no way the "tops" are going to pop off and blow around for miles. What a useless contribution on your part.

Comment: @Adrien - **Play nice Adrien, (or we will not want to help you)** I understood what you wrote, YOU misunderstood what i wrote.  I was not suggesting they would  "pop off"  I meant that if they are not supported that they would be loose  and that **possibly** the wind could move them around resulting in them **possibly** banging into each other. The sound will be very loud, Perhaps loud enough to be heard for miles. My point is, **it may not be a good idea to have the tops unsupported**.

Comment: Corrugated steel, installed properly, has a couple inches of overlap.  Holes could be drilled through that overlap area, and bolt/nut run through with fender washers.  That will keep them from rattling against each other. That with competent attachment to the wall should arrest most rattling.  You're gonna want the fender washers... only needs to be done on the top 2'  where it doesn't overlap the wall (e.g. 2-3 places should suffice, and places you could reach).

Comment: those anchor bolts are for installing in concrete when it is a fresh liquid slurry. they cannot be used in concrete that is already hard.

Comment: Off topic, but I doubt that the loophole in the city code mentioned above applies here. You're effectively raising a fence above legal height. Period. Also, this is what window blinds are for.

Comment: If your main concern is privacy for looking through the windows, have you considered getting your windows tinted? There are lots of options, some that still leave lots of light in, but don't allow looking in from outside. Might be a lot easier and cheaper than your plan.

Comment: I already proposed this idea to my partner who really hates that look. I kind of agree only because at nighttime it's pretty much useless. When it's dark outside but we have the lights on inside people can still see us. Not to mention, we want more privacy when we are outside in our yard.

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother with that anchor bolt idea.  I'd go with a lot of small anchors rather than a few big ones.  Concrete screws, Tapcon brand are popular, should work.  I'd attach the metal top, middle and bottom spaced maybe 2' horizontally.

[image: tapcon screw]

You'll need a masonry bit and a nutdriver bit the right size for the concrete screws, and a metal bit slightly larger.  I'd drill the metal first, then use the metal to locate the holes in the concrete, working bottom to top then side to side.

If you have a fairly flat concrete surface at the bottom of the wall, you could skip the bottom row of screws and hold it to the wall with either angle iron or a 2x2" strip of wood.  That would hold the bottom edge to the wall securely and might be quite a bit easier.